# Angular Material 2 text-align md-input changing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have some issues with Angular Material 2 Input.
I need to fix that.

My code

```
<md-input-container class="example-full-width">
  <input #box type="text" name="box" [(ngModel)]="keyword" mdInput placeholder="Search ">
</md-input-container>
```

Result below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1EWr.png)

How I can to fix that?

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: @digit https://jsfiddle.net/L1Lgnqor/ , but i can't do it in another way, because in project imported angular material.